# PrimeFaces wizard: update other components on step change

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, wizard

I have PrimeFaces `p:wizard` inside `p:dialog` component. I'm using the custom buttoms for next/previous step:

```
<p:commandButton value="Weiter" onclick="wiz.next()">
```

I want to change the element of the dialog, which contains the wizard, in my case it is the dialog header:

```
<p:dialog id="dialogRespWizard"
        header="#{wizardBean.header}"
```

I've changed my code to:

```
<p:commandButton value="Weiter" onclick="wiz.next()" update="dialogRespWizard">
```

But the whole dialog is dissapearing after choosing next step.

So, how can I refresh the wizard 'surrounding' on the step change?

Comment: So when you reopen the dialog, does it at least reflect the update? Is the dialog in a separate form from the rest of your markup or is it part of one huge form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regarding your question:**

The dialog disappears because you update your **whole** dialog (means that the whole dialog element will be dropped from the HTML page, and will get replaced by a new dialog HTML element received from the server), that is intentional. If you want to update something **inside** your dialog you need to make some kind of *XXXpanel* inside your dialog and update that XXXpanel (wrapping HTML dialog element will be the samel, just the content of the dialog gets replaced with a new content received from the server):

```
<p:dialog id="dialogWizard" header="something">
  <p:outputPanel id="outputPanelWizard">
    // a lot of stuff which needs to get updated
  </p:outputPanel>
  <p:commandButton .... update="outputPanelWizard" />
</p:dialog>
```

... and your dialog won't hide again. Therefore you need to put the header into a *facet* which you already have done, one step into the right direction.

**To your self-answered question**:

The "blinking" is present because you use **onclick** and **update**. *Onclick* gets executed as soon as the user clicks on the *p:commandButton*. But the *update* happens sometimes later in the cycle (when the browser received the response from the server). Therefore the wizard switches with *wiz.next()* and afterwards the *update* happens on the dialog header. You could just use **oncomplete** instead of **onclick** and the switch will happen after the browser receives the response from the server and after the dialog gets *updated* -> no more "blinking".
Some other solutions exist as well, e.g.

Don't use onclick/oncomplete/update on the p:commandButton, instead handle everything in the *action*/*actionListener* with the *RequestContext* as seen here [RequestContext Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/requestContext.jsf#j_idt27%3aj_idt30).

```
this.header = "my new header";
context.execute("wiz.next();"); 
context.update("outputPanelWizard");
```

The advantage is IMHO, that you can evaluate the form (the user input) and switch to *wiz.next()* if it is applicable or not. When the user input is not satisfying you can stay on the same page, just don't call *wiz.next()*. Same applies to the header, you can update is in the backing bean in respect to the user input.

Comment: But the problem is, that wiz.next() triggers the action on the server, so if it's not on onclick, than there is no complete...

Comment: Just execute with an *action* or *actionListener* attribtue in your *p:commandButton* a method in your backing bean, processing/updating/calculating something. After the desired values have been updated (your header for example), you just can do two things: 1.)call *context.execute("wiz.next();");. This means that this piece of javascript will be executed by the client (that "command" is received from the server), and the wiz.next() automatically switches to the next wizard-tab. 2.) use wiz.next() in the *oncomplete* from your *p:commandButton*.Dont forget *update*!

Answer (score 2):

So, I have dealt with this problem by moving the header into **facet**. In the facet I could use **outputText** with arbitrary id, and update this component by id after the wizard action.

```
<p:dialog id="dialogWizard">
<f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText id="dialogHeader" value="#{wizard.header}" />
</f:facet>

<p:commandButton value="Weiter" onclick="wiz.next()" update="dialogHeader">
```

The only problem with this solution is the visible 'blinking' of header after step change. The dialog content changes first and then after a moment the header changes, this unconcurrence is visible for the user.